# ClassNotFoundException when trying run the SparkPi example

Tags: apache-spark, scala-2.10

I'm trying to run the first example from the documentation that says:

> Spark runs on Java 6+ and Python 2.6+. For the Scala API, Spark 1.0.0
>   uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version
>   (2.10.x).

This happens when I run the command:

```
./bin/run-example examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala 10


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I'm using the version `For Hadoop 2 (HDP2, CDH5)`

already tried scala 2.9.3, 2.10.3 and 2.11

Some ideas?

Comment: Look again at the documentation. Your command does not match it. The argument is exactly "SparkPi"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the example class, not the path to a source file; try

```
./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
```

This is described in the [Running the Examples and Shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#running-the-examples-and-shell) section of the Spark documentation.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but now I have this: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.scala` any clue?

Comment: What's the exact command that you're running?  Did you try `./bin/run-example SparkPi.scala 10` with the `.scala` extension?  Try leaving that off, since that's not part of the class name.